# Does Ridley Scott's Director's Cut releases hurt his movies?

Tags: ridley-scott

While reading his wiki page it says that: Running alongside his enthusiasm for DVD, Scott is sometimes considered the "father" of the director's cut, though the impetus to produce such versions has sometimes begun with other parties. The positive reaction to the Blade Runner Director's Cut encouraged Scott to re-cut several movies that were a disappointment at the time of their release (including Legend and Kingdom of Heaven). Today the practice of alternative cuts is more commonplace, though often as a way to make a film stand out in the DVD marketplace by adding new material.

Blade Runner was his first Director's cut but he has made many since. It seems he has the most Director's Cut Editions. Also it seems that he does a lot of Director Cut because his movies are changed by studio input after test screenings. So does his making of so many Director's Cut actually hurt the movies ( since the original movie is no longer the definitive version) or help them by creating more layers?

Comment: I have SOOO many opinions on this subject, especially Ridley, but the question is unanswerable, definitively, as stated.  It’s more about debate, and opinions, than facts.  Define “hurt” first and then let’s roll!

Comment: [Related](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/625/what-are-the-differences-between-the-alternative-versions-of-blade-runner) post.  One of many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To a **strong** movie fan, no, it cannot hurt - ever.  An alternate (possibly revisionist) version of a movie cannot detract from the original viewing experience, it can only add an additional positive (or negative) experience.  In the case of Ridley and Blade Runner, I have every version, and his “Final Cut” is my favorite, and I am pleased-giddy that he was able to get yet another version released.  It is my opinion that, given 4+ versions, you have the luxury of choosing the one you enjoy most.  **You have nothing but upside!**  Any downside is for pessimists, or people who have undue hatred for capitalist who play their little games – while we are still free to play ours.

In the case of his refusal to agree to a Director’s Cut of Prometheus – that is cool too.  I enjoy the fact that as an artist Ridley Scott wraps his arms fully around the meta concept of additional releases, and indeed incorporates that into the overall art – like Claude Monet’s Water Lilies, or Haystacks – as long as HE is making the decisions.  (You might argue the opposite for 99% of all other director/studio combos.)