# What is the story behind the “made for each other” ending of Blade Runner?

Tags: ending, alternate-version, blade-runner, deleted-scenes

The 1982 movie *Blade Runner* has multiple alternate endings.  In the Director’s Cut and Final Cut the [final scene](https://youtu.be/5lPsmFSNWc4) ends with where Rick leaves his apartment along with Rachael.  The US theatrical version adds an [additional scene](https://youtube.com/watch?v=aAl07rl2jew) where Rick and Rachael are driving away through a natural landscape, with Rick saying in voiceover that Tyrell told him that Rachael is immune from the replicants’ termination date.

But now I just found one more [alternate ending](https://youtube.com/watch?v=y8t9_081E9Y).  Like the US theatrical version, it features Rick and Rachael driving through the natural landscape.  But rather than a voiceover it has a conversation between them, which ends with Rachael saying “I think we were made for each other,” with the obvious implication that Rick is a replicant.

My question is, what is the history of this scene?  At what point of the production process, if ever, was this scene intended to be included in the movie?  And why was it dropped?  Clearly this scene is what they made the theatrical ending out of, but I’d like any more available information.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner#Versions , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Versions_of_Blade_Runner , https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/625/what-are-the-differences-between-the-alternative-versions-of-blade-runner , https://www.reddit.com/r/bladerunner/comments/bc5am7/45_minutes_of_blade_runner_deleted_and_alternate/ , http://mrpeelsardineliqueur.blogspot.com/2007/12/made-for-each-other.html , etc.

Comment: @BCdotWEB None of those links answer my question unfortunately.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan They do. You just have to glue the things. Scott didn't "do" voice-overs. As "happy ending" don't appear in Final cut it might be filmed by Scott but not used by HIM. But as the voice-over and happy ending were done by studio they used this "happy ending" and change the outcome by removing the dialogue and replacing with off-camera voice.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Well, what I want to know is, at what point of the production process did Scott intend for this scene to be in the movie, and when/why he decided to drop it (if he’s the one who made that decision).

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan In the link it's explained that voice-over and happy ending were added by studio after first screening. Scott insisted that Deckards was a replicant so that ending audio is in line with his statements. But it's also not very happy. Therefore studio decided to dub the audio with voice over to create less disturbing ending. Why Scott didn't included this scene as ending? Judging by Final Cut he preffered to end earlier leaving much more open ending.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY But was there ever a point where the scene with dialogue was part of the movie? Or was it never even added to any cut of the movie? And has Scott ever discussed when/why he put it in and when/why he took it out?

Comment: I just today saw this and I think it was the first time I ever heard of this. Very unsubtle implication that  RD is a replicant. Also, the landscape, presumably the area north of San Francisco, is very much at odds with the ecological disaster that the world is supposed to have experienced. (SF is setting for book -- maybe Los Angeles is setting for movie so maybe this area is someplace else in CA). Deckard does not seem happy with the idea that he is a replicant as I would guess no one would be.